# Using google cloud storage from pc application

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Hopefully I don't sound too stupid asking this. My wife and I run a small business out of our home. We want to share the accounting data, but I'm at another location often. We use a PC version of Sage Peachtree Premium Accounting that has networking capabilities, so the data files can be stored in a common place. Is it possible to share this file using something like Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage is probably overkill for what you're talking about. Cloud Storage is something web developers use to deliver assets like images, videos, and documents to a large number of users around the world.

However something like Google Drive or Dropbox would probably work well for this. If you both have Gmail accounts then Google Drive is a natural choice. Both of these solutions have a service which runs on each PC and automatically syncs changed files in a specified folder to all other computers using that folder.

So if one of you makes changes to the file, it will show up in the other location automatically. However the real question is how your software will handle this. I'm not familiar with Peachtree Accounting but it probably isn't possible for you to both be making changes at the same time, unless the software is specifically designed for that use case.

If you can post a link or description for the "networking capabilities" (that is a rather vague term on its own) it may be possible to tell for sure.

Comment: I gave it a try, and so far it seems to work. I had to set it so my wife and I both use the same Google drive, and set the company database files to store there. We'll see after we try it for a while.

Comment: When you say "use the same Google drive" do you mean the same login? You don't have to do that, one of you can just create a folder and then "share" it to the other. That way you avoid the hassle of having to switch between your Gmail account and the one you use for Drive.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work this time. Unless I just missed something on how a Google drive works. I first installed the program on my computer, that already had my Google drive installed, using my email login. I told the software to locate the files unique to the company's records on the Google drive.

Comment: I then did the same on my wife's computer using her Google drive login using her Gmail address. I then set up sharing the Google drive on my account. letting her share it. The problem is the software wants to use the copies on the computer drive, not the online share link. In other words, she needs the files physically on her hard drive like they are on mine.

Comment: I tried to connect hers using the Google share link, but it wouldn't let it work. The only way I could get it to work is have the exact same files on both hard drives, and shared on Google. The only way that seemed to work is use the same Gmail login. if there is another way I'm open to try. This is all just an experiment still.

Comment: Well if it's working for you then no need to change it. But if you'd rather each use your "own" logins and not deal with it that's possible too. You need to get all the files you need in your folder, share that folder with her (add her as a collaborator with "Can Edit" permission, not just share the link), and have her move that shared folder to her "My Drive" folder so it syncs locally.

Comment: More info on syncing shared folders (in particular the "Items Shared With Me" section): http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375083 .. General info on sharing/syncing: http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494822 http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375189

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive is certainly the cheaper option as it is optimized for consumer usage patterns. Google Cloud Storage is optimized for applications that demand highly available and replicated storage with strong global consistency.

Here are a few ways that Google Cloud Storage attempts to improve team collaboration:

1. Resources are owned by a project team composed of multiple people.
2. It is possible to share files with a group.
3. It is possible to change the default acl applied to new objects.

#### Collaborate with a team

Each bucket is owned by a project and by default everyone on your team can read new objects upload to those buckets.

You manage the people on your team in the following manner:

- Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console
- Click on teams on the sidebar.
- Add the email addresses of other people you want to collaborate with.
- Use the drop-down list to give them more permissions.
- Use the x to remove team members.

Permissions are concentric:

- Everyone with `can view` access will be able to read files that do not specify an acl.
- Everyone with `can edit` access will also be able to create and delete buckets as well as upload new objects.
- Everyone with `is owner` access will also be able to add other viewers, editors and owners.

#### Share to a Google Group

Google Cloud Storage allows you to share files with a Google group. User gain access to these files when you add them to the group and lose access when you remove them from the group.

First download the objects acl:

```
gsutil getacl gs://bucket/obj > acl.xml
vim acl.xml
```

Now add the following acl entry inside the `<Entries/>` tag:

```
  <Entry>
    <Scope type="GroupByEmail">
      <!-- Give everyone in the gs-discussion group READ access. -->
      <EmailAddress>gs-discussion@googlegroups.com</EmailAddress>
    </Scope>
    <Permission>READ</Permission>
  </Entry>
```

Now update the acl:

```
gsutil setacl acl.xml gs://bucket/obj
```

See the online documentation for further information about access control https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#applyacls

You can create a Google group at google.com/groups

#### Change the default object acl

By default everyone on the team can read objects you upload. However you can configure this to be more or less permissive. You could make objects publicly-readable by default or only viewable by the owner and a Google group.

Changing the default object acl is similar to changing object acls. Just use the `getdefacl` and `setdefacl` commands.

Some predefined configurations do not require editing an xml file:

```
# Team members can view new objects.
gsutil setdefacl project-private gs://bucket
# Anonymous internet users can view new objects.
gsutil setdefacl public-read gs://bucket
```

Otherwise you can edit the acl xml:

```
gsutil getdefacl gs://bucket > def_acl.xml
vim def_acl.xml
# Add whichever UserByEmail, GroupByEmail, AllUsers, etc grants you want.
gsutil setdefacl def_acl.xml gs://bucket
```

New objects apply the default object acl:

```
gsutil cp foo gs://bucket  # This object will receive the def_acl.xml acls.
```

It is easy to override the default object acl with a predefined acl for a particular object:

```
# Ignore the default acl. Use public-read.
gsutil cp -a public-read foo gs://bucket
```

The full list of predefined acls is available at developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#extension